# Partitioning Data for K fold Cross Validation that will not have Equal Partitions

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

From Wikipedia:

> In k-fold cross-validation, the original sample is randomly
>   partitioned into k equal size subsamples.

I am working on a 10 fold cross validation project. I have a dataset that has 76 elements. It means that I can not have equal size partitions.

What are the approaches for remaining data (in my example 6 data)? Ignoring them, making a data 16 elements, 6 partitions have 11 elements or etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not ignore them !!

Simply, you may distribute the 6 data points randomly over the 10 folds.

Another way is to just add them to any of the folds. At the end, these points will be passed for testing once as supposed to be done.

Answer (score 0):

You have two simple options. If you really want to use 10 fold validation, have some of the folds with seven elements and some with eight. It won't really matter. Alternatively, use four fold validation, with 19 elements in each fold.

Either is fine, you're unlikely to see that much of a difference. It's rare that you'd get exactly equal folds, but because your dataset is small you might see greater variance between the folds as the number of training examples changes. I doubt it, however.